# Why do subscriptions load the processor 100%

Tags: vue.js, graphql, hasura

I get statistics from hasura in the following way

FrontEnd(nuxt.js)

```
<script>
import subUsers from '~/apollo/subscriptions/stats/users'
import users from '~/apollo/queries/stats/users'

export default {
  apollo: {
    users: {
      query: users,
      update: data => data.users_aggregate.aggregate.count,
      subscribeToMore: {
        document: subUsers,
        updateQuery: (previousResult, { subscriptionData }) => {
          return {
            users_aggregate: subscriptionData.data.users_aggregate
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Hasura:

```
query users {
  users_aggregate {
    aggregate {
      count
    }
  }
}
```

```
subscription users {
  users_aggregate {
    aggregate {
      count
    }
  }
}
```

In the table `user` I have about 500,000 users

And because of the subscriptions, I have all the processor cores loaded 100%
[image]

[image: htop]

Comment: I assume you have either a duo or quad cores processors, that's pretty normal since you have 500,000 users, involving multiple tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the query of the subscription to be able to work very fast. One way to make it fast is to cache the count itself after every change. You can implement this using a trigger on your user table. The cached value is stored into a `user_aggregate` table on which you can now subscribe. For example:

```sql
drop table if exists user_aggregate;
drop trigger if exists user_aggregate_trigger on user_info;
drop function if exists user_aggregate();

create table user_aggregate (
    id int not null primary key,
    user_aggregate int not null
);

create or replace function user_aggregate()
returns trigger
as $$
begin
    insert into user_aggregate (id, user_aggregate)
    values (1, (select count(id) from user_info))
    on conflict (id) do
    update set user_aggregate = excluded.user_aggregate;
    return new;
end
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger user_aggregate_trigger
after insert or delete on user_info
for each row execute procedure user_aggregate();

insert into user_aggregate (id, user_aggregate)
values (1, (select count(id) from user_info))
on conflict (id) do
update set user_aggregate = excluded.user_aggregate;
```

You might want to disable the trigger if you are batch inserting/deleting a lot of users.

Answer (score 3):

Hasura implements subscriptions via interval-based polling, which basically means that your query is run every 1 second. You can read the details about the architectural decisions here:

- https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/blob/master/architecture/live-queries.md

Since you're running an aggregation query over 500k rows every second, well...

So what can you do? Postgres has just the solution for you and it's called materialized views. You create one such view based on the aggregate you want and then tell PG to update it only when it makes sense. So in your case, you would update it every time a user is added or removed. Then you subscribe to your view and its cost is basically nothing (since the view remembers the query result until updated).

Comment: Did but nothing has changed ;(